# Gulp Automatização de arquivo JS

Tags: javascript, gulp, gulpjs

Minha dúvida é a seguinte, tenho um arquivo .js no meu código que contem um monte de variaveis que só muda o valor delas.

Exemplo:

```
var teste = "http://desenvolvimento.com.br";
var teste = "http://producao.com.br";
```

Após rodar o gulp eu gostaria de passar algum parametro.

Exemplo:

```
gulp producao
//var teste = "http://desenvolvimento.com.br";
var teste = "http://producao.com.br";
```

Basicamente ao rodar o parametro gulp producao ou gulp desenvolvimento ele automaticamente comentava as váriaveis que tem os apontamentos diferente de produção.

Answer (score 0):

Há uma global que está disponivel dentro do ficheiro `.js` que é `process`. Essa global tem uma chave `process.argv` que contem os argumentos usados para iniciar o comando. Um exemplo seria:

Para `gulp producao` o `process.argv` será `['node', 'caminho/para/gulp.js', 'producao']`, se passares mais argumentos elese vão aparecer nessa array.

Assim, no caso específico da posição de `producao` seria `process.argv[2]`, e o que pretendes portanto será:

```
const teste = process.argv[2] === 'producao' ? 'http://producao.com.br' : 'http://desenvolvimento.com.br';
```